# How to write a SPARQL query to pull from OWL file

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, jena, protege

So this is my owl File I absolutely new to Jena/SQL items so I am just trying to test it out.
prefix part:

```xml
<Ontology xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/5/test-ontology-2
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     ontologyIRI="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/5/test-ontology-2>
    <Prefix name="" IRI="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/5/test-ontology-2/>
    <Prefix name="owl" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"/>
    <Prefix name="rdf" IRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"/>
    <Prefix name="xml" IRI="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>
    <Prefix name="xsd" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"/>
    <Prefix name="rdfs" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"/>
```

I am attempting to write one to just pull anything that shows `hasConcept`. However, I know the `hasConcept` is part of the prefix? I think that is what it is called. So I'm not sure how to just filter it to pull it.

```xml
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/5/test-ontology- 
 2#Structures">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/5/test-ontology-2#Course"/>
    <untitled-ontology-2:hasConcept 
rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/5/test-ontology-2#Cong"/>
    <untitled-ontology-2:hasConcept 
rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/5/test-ontology-2#Func"/>
    <untitled-ontology-2:hasTopic rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/5/test- 
ontology-2#Time"/>
    <untitled-ontology-2:courseNumber>CMSC 2123</untitled-ontology-2:courseNumber>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

I've tried going through the documentation on Apache Jena which I can understand through their example for RDF but I still get a little confused mainly because I'm not a good programmer so concepts are still hard for me to understand.

But I'm just trying any help would be greatly appreciated.
I'm not sure how to pull just the #func,#cong,#time part or if it is even possible to pull just this section.

Comment: the prefix is `untitled-ontology-2` the prefixed URI of the property is `untitled-ontology-2:hasConcept`, in SPARQL you would write it without angle brackets, i.e. `PREFIX untitled-ontology-2: <THE NAME SPACE HERE PLEASE> SELECT * WHERE{ ?s untitled-ontology-2:hasConcept ?o }` - indeed, a shorted prefix name in the SPARQL query makes sense, it's your decision.

Comment: OH I see, Do I need to add all the prefix? I saw examples that had like
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> and the 
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

Comment: you don't have to add any prefix at all if you don't want. It's just syntactic sugar to make queries more compact and readable. The full URI can always be used, i.e. `SELECT * WHERE{ ?s `<THE NAME SPACE HERE PLEASE/hasConcept> ?o }`

Comment: So I ran  the query but it came out to 
```Query:
PREFIX  owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  untitled-ontology-2: <http://http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/5/test-ontology-2>
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX  <base:http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/5/test-ontology-2#>
SELECT  *WHERE { ?s <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/5/test-ontology- 
 2#Structures>  untitled-ontology-2:hasConcept }```

Comment: well ... `Structures` is the subject and not the object of the RDF triple, please look at your data again. Also I don't get why you used the prefixed URI notation for `hasConcept` but not for `Structure`. And I also told you that you can the prefix a shorter name - the whole purpose is to make the query more compact and readable. And in your current query you neither use an RDFS or an OWL entity, so why did you add the prefix declarations for those vocabularies?

Comment: Oh I didn't realize this just took the old one I was attempting I must've not hit copy paste correctly. I am sorry for that based off what you told me in the earlier comment I didn't need to add the prefix anywhere. So I took that out and just ran
 ```"select * where  { ?s <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/5/untitled-ontology-2#/hasConcept> ?o }"```; which ran and came out as
```---------
| s | o |
=========
---------```

Comment: now the URI is wrong ... again, please look carefully at your data! the namespace of the prefix is `http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/5/untitled-ontology-2#` and when in the data the prefixed URI occurs it is a simple as it is, just concatenate the strings. There is no slash trailing `/` in the namespace declaration

Comment: Yes, I got it now...... I am so sorry!! Thank you so much for helping me on this

Comment: great. now you can continue working with SPARQL - and don't worry, there begging can be confusing, but once you got used to, it can become fun and very powerful.